# Нужны ли тире и запятая (в скобках) в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Их суть (—) в умении строить человеческие взаимоотношения, создавать, воспитывать себя, побуждать, поддерживать в людях постоянное желание действовать, мотивировать и себя(,) и других.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужны ли тире

Полагаю, что тире нужно в обязательном порядке.

> и запятая (в скобках) в этом предложении?

Запятая не нужна. В том смысле, что необязательна, более того, сомнительна даже как факультативный знак.

***Их суть — в умении строить человеческие взаимоотношения, создавать, воспитывать себя, побуждать, поддерживать в людях постоянное желание действовать, мотивировать и себя и других.***

Подробнее — ниже.

**О тире.**

> 1. Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических предложениях
>    (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым):
>    ...
>    *Её [литературы] красота — в истине, её главное значение — в правде (Кор.)*
>    ...

Розенталь
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

Я процитировал только один пример, но он предельно близок рассматриваемой фразе.
Кроме того, есть еще правило, что тире ставится, если иными способами нельзя передать смысл фразы.

**О запятой.**

Правило о тесном смысловом единстве на самом-то деле можно отнести к разделу так называемой авторской пунктуации. Никто, кроме автора, не скажет наверняка, есть оно тут или нет. Но в данном случае естественно будет считать, что оно все-таки есть, если, конечно, автор не стремится к какой-то оригинальности. Основанием для такой трактовки может служить то, что тесное смысловое единство обычно составляют пары, дополняющие друг друга до какого-то целостного множества, выражаемого словами *всех, весь* и подобными: и день и ночь (=весь день), и мальчики и девочки (=все дети), и природа и человек (=всё окружение).

Розенталь дает массу подходящих примеров.

> При двух однородных членах предложения с повторяющимся союзом *и*
> запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно
> такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов): Кругом
> было и светло и зелено (Т.); Он носил и лето и зиму старую жокейскую
> кепку (Пауст.); Прибрежная полоса, пересечённая мысами, уходила и в ту
> и в другую сторону (Сем.); Он был и весел и печален в одно и то же
> время.
>
> Такие смысловые единства образуются словами с ассоциативными (часто
> антонимическими) связями: и брат и сестра; и родители и дети; и отцу и
> матери; и с сыном и с дочерью; и друзья и враги; и слава и позор; и
> зрение и слух; и тело и душа; и глухой и немой; и море и горы; и
> музыка и пение; и стихи и проза; и любовь и ненависть; и радость и
> горе; и зимой и летом; и ножи и вилки; и блюдца и чашки; и он и она.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101

В нашем случае — **"и себя и других"** равно **"всех"**.

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, что это "вкусовые" знаки: с одной стороны... а с другой стороны...

Первое тире я бы оставила - для меня очевиден (слышен) пропуск сказуемого ("заключается"), про запятую тоже бабушка надвое сказала: очень просится "смысловое единство" (т. е. не надо знака), ну а если вы (читающий, пишущий) его не усматриваете? О_о

[Вопрос № 287179](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20287179)

> Добрый день! нужна ли запятая во фразе: "И я(,) и ты"
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Не зная контекста, можем только привести общее правило. При двух
> однородных членах предложения с повторяющимся союзом и запятая не
> ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство. Если такого
> единства нет, запятая нужна.

---

*Их суть - в умении строить человеческие взаимоотношения, создавать, воспитывать себя, побуждать, поддерживать в людях постоянное желание действовать, мотивировать и себя и других.*

Comment: Ага! Вижу, что все утряслось. С возвращением! В поддержку Вашего ответа: **и себя и других** — с запятой и без. (https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&text=lexform&req=%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&endyear=2019&nodia=1&p=0) Думаю, надо поправить: _...(т. е. не надо знака). Ну а если вы (читающий, пишущий) его не усматриваете?_ И — бонус, конечно.

Comment: Римулька, спасибо за поддержку! А очевидные очепятки надо править смело - не оставлять товарища с ослиными ухами, вот.